# Get current datetime in JS for a specific timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am working on a platform that has users from all over the world, but certain settings are bound to a predefined timezone datetime.

What does this mean? If a user connects from a different timezone the app should still show him the current time in the predefined timezone regardles from where he logs in. I need to calculate this on the client side with javascript with only the timezone string.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
new TimezoneDate('timezone');
```

and the result should be the current datetime for that timezone.

I know there are JS libs that handle this but I am asking if there is a simple JS solution without using external libs?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your definition of simple; but not really. Javascript does not have support for timezones out of the box. I would highly recommend Moment Timezone http://momentjs.com/timezone/ since it is very user friendly. I am also in the middle of a project with the same requirements and this library has made my work a lot easier.

Edit:
With the library, doing what you want is as easy as:

```
var timezonedDate = moment.tz('YOUR TZ STRING').toDate();
```

Comment: He said that he doesn't want to use any external library.

Comment: If anyone else stumbles upon here, its very difficult to do this without an external library as there is very little native support for something like this. So momentjs is a nice to have npm package.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

Or to get the difference in hours:

```
var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

[Mozilla Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

> The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and
>   local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the
>   local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead. For example,
>   if your time zone is UTC+10 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), -600
>   will be returned. Daylight saving time prevents this value from being
>   a constant even for a given locale.

Comment: This solution does not meet the requirement of getting the current datetime from a given timezone string.

Comment: @GPicazo I think it can help him. He can just substract or add the offset to his time and show the same to any user.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't mean it wasn't helpful, just that it didn't address the question directly, but you are right about it being useful. I would think it really depends on whether getting the current DateTime is the only timezone-specific requirement he has or if he will have to perform other tz related operations (date computations).